# rotate curved textPath in d3

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have created a few curved text path, but don't know the way to rotate the upside-down text like "Stone Mill Court", "Maginn Drive".

[image]

I have the following code:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h);

svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr('id', function(d, i) { return 'curve-' + i; })
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("fill", 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1);

svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(features)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) { return 'curve-text-' + i; })
// Something needs to be done here to rotate the text.
    .append("textPath")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) { return '#curve-' + i; })
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.label
      });
```